# Technique behind showing previously loaded data when network connection off

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-asynctask

**Case 1:** *app open when network connection off*

app  want keep showing  previously  loaded data from server

**Case 2:** *app open when network connection on*

app want to fetching data from server and update

**What is the technique behind this**

eg:

> facebook app

Comment: you have to save your data somewhere. You can use shared preferences or sqlite database to store the data.

Comment: you need to provide offline support for this feature. you can use Db for this.

Comment: use `Database`, load data from database and sync your data when internet is available.

Comment: any body can share use full links with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Sqlite DataBase and update data whenever network is available
Next time when app starts, check if network is not available or not

- If not available load the stored data from DB
- If network is available then get the updates and stores in same DB
- either you can override or add to the existing data

   **Edit 1:** 
  You can store the downloaded images in memory(internal/external)
  Store the saved path directory in DB . Refer the link [sample implementation of loading image asynchronously](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-asynchronous-image-loading-in-listview/) and this also [Picasso reference link](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: @ harry thanks but how can i save image ?

Comment: For images the best option is to use a lib like  UniversalImageLoader, Glide or Picasso. That provide you a stable solution that do all the work for you

Comment: @ An-droid ... thanks

Comment: i dont want to save image to memory .....  i want to working app like face book app ...there is not saving image to memory

Comment: check the picasso implementation link. You dont need to take care of downloading and saving images. Library will take care of those

Comment: @ harry thanks   for your contribution

Answer (score 1):

### For configurations data use SharedPreferences

For bigger datas you can parse local Json or xml files

The best solution is always a database (sqlite)
You can also couple it with a ContentManager and Use cursorAdapter for your lists

Common tuto : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Official doc : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

---

Images management (pick the one that suits you best):

UIL : https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Picasso : http://square.github.io/picasso/

Glide : https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: thanks  can you share any links related about this